# non-literal uses of "chugging away"?

Tags: expressions

What is the most common non-literal use of the expression "chugging away"? I've heard it in the context of:

```
The machine is switched on and *chugging away*.
```

Comment: Your example **is** a literal usage - the machine is switched on and *making a rhythmic 'chugging' sound*. The most common non-literal use of *chugging* is when *chugging **along*** is used to mean *making steady progress* - which can occur in contexts where there's no associated rhythmic "machine-like" sound involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Chug* is onomatopoeia for the noise a train makes as it goes along. If a train is *chugging away* is it making the sound that means it is working.

So *chugging away* is a metaphorical way of saying *working*, i.e doing what it's meant to be doing.

For example, you might say:

> Ahh, look at granddad chugging away in the garden. He looks so happy.

Comment: I can't go with that example. *Chug* is so strongly associated with the **sound** that it's bordering on "marked" to use *chugging away* in any context where there's no obvious repetitive noise. You'd get far more examples for metaphoric *chugging along*, where the sense is of *making steady progress* even if there's no implication of any accompanying rhythmic engine sound.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think you are making too much of a distinction between `along` and `away`: one which does not really exist in nature. Indeed `Matt` is using it metaphorically, and there is no requirement for the implication of sound to be represented by the metaphor.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree that _chug_ is most often associated with the sound of a train, but I don't believe an accompanying _along_ is needed to use it idiomatically, i.e. to allude to _working on a laborious path toward a particular aim_, much like _chug_ and _chugger_ are used in [this article](http://www.usatoday.com/sports/baseball/dailypitch/2002-07-23-pitch_x.htm).

Comment: @horatio: Google Books: ["I chugged along"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+chugged+along%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - 595 hits; ["I chugged away"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+chugged+away%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - 28 hits. Admittedly a small sample, but even among those 28 (actually only 13 when GB is asked to show the details) it seems to me most of them are "semi-literal, sound-associated" - *"chugging away in a clapped out old banger"*, for example.

Comment: I follow what you are saying, but I think your search is confounded by your choice of terms. Googling `chugging away` even brings up a news item with "chugging away" in the title and a quote about "chugging along" (the editors see them as interchangeable). Note also that "chug" means to drink quickly without pause and this meaning is widespread, complicating the metaphor. And finally, metaphors are highly plastic.

Comment: @horatio: Well let's be clear. I'm not saying no-one *ever* uses *"chug"* the way Matt has here - obviously he's just done it himself. I'm saying it's *not very common* relative to the number of times it's used where chugging sounds *are* implied. And I chose to GB "**I**" to make sure I only got *people* (not anthropomorphised "he" Thomas the Tank Engine, for example). That clearly showed *chugged along* is far more common than *away*, which was really a secondary point. I do know all the other meanings (incl. to take deep drags on a cigarette, related to the drinking sense).